# How to use call a function on a clickable item on Angular 8?

Tags: angular8

I have the following icon :

```
 <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

When trying to call a method belong to the .ts of this component, it does not work :

```
 <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true" (onClick)="viewHelpMultimedia()"></i>
```

The method is properly defined on the typescript, and the Angular CLI compiles successfully.

Can someone help with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not having declared DynamicDialog as a provider on the typescript of the component